# Angular not rendering correct html after link change

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular so please bear with me.

My admin-documentaries.component.html has the following text:
`<p>admin-documentaries works!</p>`

My admin-home.component.html has the following text:

```
<p>admin-home works!</p>


<a [routerLink]="['/admin/home']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Home
  </a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/documentaries']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Documentaries
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/comments']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Comments
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/users']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Users
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/activity']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Activity
</a>
```

However when I click on Documentaries the text stays as the admin home.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8qek.png)

admin-documentaries.component.ts

```
import { DocumentaryService } from './../../services/documentary.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-documentaries',
  templateUrl: './admin-documentaries.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-documentaries.component.css']
})
export class AdminDocumentariesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: DocumentaryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let documentaries = this.service.getAll().subscribe();
    console.log(documentaries);
  }

}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { AdminDocumentariesComponent } from './admin/admin-documentaries/admin-documentaries.component';
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './admin/admin-home/admin-home.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'admin', component: AdminHomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'documentaries', component: AdminDocumentariesComponent },
    ]
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<h2><router-outlet></router-outlet> </h2>
```

Thanks

Error:

```
ERROR <unavailable> vendor.js:44758:33
    defaultErrorLogger http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44758
    handleError http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:44810
    next http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69185
    schedulerFn http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65417
    __tryOrUnsub http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:90109
    next http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:90048
    _next http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:89996
    next http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:89973
    next http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:89759
    emit http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:65379
    onHandleError http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68514
    invoke http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3208
    run http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2973
    runOutsideAngular http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68401
    onHandleError http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68511
    handleError http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3212
    runGuarded http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2986
    microtaskDrainDone http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3512
    drainMicroTaskQueue http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3415
    invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3318
    invokeTask http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4452
    globalZoneAwareCallback http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4478
```

**Edit**

When I remove

```
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/home']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Home
  </a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/documentaries']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Documentaries
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/comments']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Comments
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/users']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Users
</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/admin/activity']" routerLinkActive="active">
    Activity
</a>
```

and replace it with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` I get the following:
[admin documentaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7mpC.png)

Comment: Are you seeing any error in the console? If so what does it say?

Comment: @nash11 I updated with the only error im receiving.

Comment: I guess you must have imported your `app-routing.module.ts` in `app.module.ts` 
`documentaries` is just your subscription what are you achieving by logging it?
instead, declare a function in it for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might not be because of this, but a correction to your code. `[routerLink]` is used to bind but you are not binding and using string for router link.

```
<a routerLink="/admin/home" routerLinkActive="active">
    Home
  </a>
<a routerLink="/admin/documentaries" routerLinkActive="active">
    Documentaries
</a>
<a routerLink="/admin/comments" routerLinkActive="active">
    Comments
</a>
<a routerLink="/admin/users" routerLinkActive="active">
    Users
</a>
<a routerLink="/admin/activity" routerLinkActive="active">
    Activity
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your subscribe to:

```
ngOnInit() {

 this.service.getAll().subscribe(
result => {
  this.documentaries = result;
  console.log(documentaries);
}
);}
```

also, declare the variable "documentaries" outside of the ngOnInit

```
 public documentaries;


 constructor( ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you have not added a `router-outlet` for your `admin` route to display its child routes. This is why when you replace your links with `router-outlet` in your `admin-home.component.html` and navigate to `/admin/documentaries` in your browser, you see the admin-documentaries being shown.

In your application, your `AppComponent` is your application shell where you have your `app-navbar` and a `router-outlet` where the router swaps components on and off the page. When the `AdminHomeComponent` loads in the AppComponent's `router-outlet`, since it has child routes, you will need to add a `router-outlet` to the parent route's template in order to display them, which is the `AdminHomeComponent` template.

Here is an example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-child-route) of the same.